How to troubleshoot and reset keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio 2019?
In Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, I used to be able to use the Ctrl+Alt+l (small L, not big i) keyboard shortcut to change focus to the Solution Explorer (corresponding to the View.SolutionExplorer command ID). However, this keybinding has stopped working. When I hold Ctrl and Alt simultaneously and press l, it doesn't seem to do anything.
I've already checked Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and verified that Ctrl+Alt+l is still assigned to View.SolutionExplorer.

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2019 to:

View a history or log of what actions keyboard shortcuts are actually triggering when pressed?
Determine when and by what (possibly an extension) a keyboard shortcut was modified?
Reset a specific keyboard shortcut back to its default setting?

What I've tried:

Checking the keyboard mappings in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
Verified that Ctrl+Alt+L is still mapped to View.SolutionExplorer

Any help in troubleshooting this keyboard shortcut issue would be appreciated.

Did you install any extension last time? Please check if your VS is updated as well, I remember there was simmilar problem some time ago and they release fix for it.

@1_bug running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" update --quiet --channelId "VisualStudio.16.Release" --productId "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional" I got this sowing that I have the latest version, and the issue still persists.

Does it work if you select from the main menu View - Solution Explorer?

@SergeyVlasov yes that one works.

I was experiencing an issue in Visual Studio 2019 where the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+L (used to focus the Solution Explorer) stopped working. Here's how I resolved it:

Check for Conflicting Shortcuts:

Navigate to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard.
In the "Press shortcut keys" field, press Ctrl+Alt+L.
Under "Shortcut currently used by:", I found that the extension Code Graph was also assigned to this shortcut, causing a conflict.





Disable the Conflicting Extension:

Go to Extensions > Manage Extensions > Installed.
Find Code Graph and click Disable.
Restart Visual Studio to apply the changes.



After disabling the conflicting extension, the Ctrl+Alt+L shortcut worked correctly again, bringing focus to the Solution Explorer.
Note: While this resolved my specific issue, Visual Studio doesn't seem to offer a built-in way to view a history of keyboard shortcut actions or determine when and by what a shortcut was modified. The general approach to troubleshoot keyboard shortcut issues appears to be:

Check for Conflicts: Use the Keyboard settings to see if multiple commands or extensions are using the same shortcut.
Manage Extensions: Disable extensions that might interfere with the keybindings.
Reassign Shortcuts: Manually reassign the shortcut to the desired command in the Keyboard settings.

This method helps identify and resolve conflicts that prevent shortcuts from functioning as expected.
